# can't append to jQuery wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't you append to an element that you use to wrap another - see example below?

```js
var $test = $('.test'),
    $test1 = $('.test1'),
    $move = $('.move'),
    $testWrapper = $('<div class="test-wrapper"></div>'),
    $test1Wrapper = $('<div class="test1-wrapper"></div>');


$test.wrap($testWrapper);
// move item and return to wrapper
$move.append($test);
$testWrapper.append($test); // this is the line that does not work?
console.log($testWrapper);   // still seems to be a jquery object?

$test1.after($test1Wrapper); // if you place the element after instead of using it to wrap, then it works?
$move.append($test1);
$test1Wrapper.append($test1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test1">test 1</div>
<div class="move"></div>
```

Comment: You are trying to append the wrapper to the wrapped content this is kind of an infinite loop...

Comment: @n00dl3 not really test is it's own object, the wrapper is it's own object, I only wrap once and then move one object out then try to move it back

Comment: Aw... didn't see the move part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wrap()` seems to clone the markup of the provided element for wrapping, not the actual element itself. You can see it in the developer tools when you use `console.log($testWrapper)` and hover over that line in your browser console: normally, the DOM element should be highlighted, but it's not. So what is referenced by the variable `$testWrapper` after wrapping is still (a jQuery collection of) a node that is not attatched to the DOM.

```js
var $test = $('.test'),
    $test1 = $('.test1'),
    $move = $('.move'),
    $testWrapper = $('<div class="test-wrapper"></div>');


$test.wrap($testWrapper);
// move item and return to wrapper
$move.append($test);
console.log($testWrapper); // <= if you hover this element in the browser console, it doesn't highlight the actual DOM element either; that's how you can visully detect that it's not the same element!
$testWrapper = $('.test-wrapper'); // select the actual DOM element that has been created for wrapping
$testWrapper.append($test); // now it will work!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="move"></div>
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I guess that it would need to make a clone as if you had multiple objects, you couldn't wrap the one element around multiple.  I actually just read the manual again and reading it more carefully, it does actually say it creates a copy of the html structure

Comment: I dug a little further - if you add the wrapper element to the DOM first, it will work as initially expected. See updated code.

Comment: Oh... No I was wrong, it creates another copy. :) So my answer stands as it was.

Comment: Hahaha, that would have been confusing!